# Unable to hide .php extensions from my site, how do I do it?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using this code

```
 # Apache Rewrite Rules
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

# Add trailing slash to url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
 </IfModule>
```

It doesn't hide .php extensions from my pages, when I remove '.php' from my anchor tags, the page get redirected.
For eg. if url is `www.example.com/mysite/store.php` and when I remove '.php' from URI or anchor href, the new url becomes `www.example.com/store/` which is not available off course. I tried to manually enter url as `example.com/mysite/store` but it is unavailable too.

Apparently .htaccess is not using these rules, if I write gibberish there,  get a 500 server error, so .htaccess is working fine but what wrong is I'm doing.

Advice.
Thanks in advice!

**Update**

Okay, I've figured it out, I successfully achieved what I asked in question. But my bootsrap is completely broken, I guess because it is linking 'bootstrap.css' as 'bootstrap.css.php' because the .htaccess file I'm now using is :

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine  on
# If the request doesn't end in .php (Case insensitive) continue processing rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
# If the request doesn't end in a slash continue processing the rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
# Rewrite the request with a .php extension. L means this is the 'Last' rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

**Update 2**

Sorry, this was not the problem as I mentioned in last update as after I stripped the bootstrap links in my index.php, I got different results. The problem is: `localhost/example/index.php` is my homepage but localhost/example is what is shown in url. `localhost/example` is a directory with files in it. So images that should be loaded as `localhost/example/image/logo.png` is loaded as `localhost/example/index.php/image/logo.png` making example site behave weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check already posted answers:

[Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you @Sid, I got this to work, apparently. Just one thing, when I click the link, this .htaccess just removes the appended .php in url, thus page is not found error is displayed. Any idea how to get that to work. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, I've figured it out, I successfully achieved what I asked in question. But my bootsrap is completely broken, I guess because it is linking 'bootstrap.css' as 'bootstrap.css.php' because the .htaccess file I'm now using is : (See Update in Question)

Comment: I have added condition to ignore css, js and image files...hope this helps